# Change visibility of a control in SCSS from nested class

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have a HTML as below.

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 account">

            <label>Account*</label>
            
 <**customcomponent**
    #hierarchyaccountsngselect
    formControlName="account"
    placeholder="Select account"
    (onChange)="onHierarchyAccountChange($event)">
    
            </**customcomponent**>
            
*<div id="error" class="invalid-input">Select one of the values from dropdown list.</div>*

</div>
```

In the custom component I am accessing styles of ng-select using :host ::ng-deep and changing the border color if the field is empty.

```css
:host ::ng-deep {
.account app-hierarchyaccounts-ng-select.ng-invalid{
    .ng-select.ng-touched {
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #dc3545;          
/* set div id="error" visibility hide/block here */
      }    
}
}
```

Now I need to set the visibility of the div with id="error" when the above nested class .ng-select.ng-touched is applied.

Can anyone help me with this on how to access the outside selectors from a nested css?

Thanks in Advance.

I tried with @media query and variables. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like that:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .account app-hierarchyaccounts-ng-select.ng-invalid {
    .ng-select.ng-touched {
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #dc3545;

      /* Set div id="error" visibility */
      #error {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But pay attention that the **::ng-deep** combinator is **deprecated**, and you should avoid using it if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response Roksarr. I have tried exactly the same before but this didn't work. I think this is because the div with ID #error is located outside the nested styles. We can achieve this If we can somehow get access to an element which is outside the nested selectors by ID or style.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz example to better demonstrate what you're suggesting? It would be really helpful to see your code in action and understand how it all fits together.

Comment: Yes, I have it created here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrgs9x.  I need to show "Select one of the values from the dropdown list." error message when the dropdown is touched but nothing is selected without making any modifications to dropdowncomp.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you need to make it like that? 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5tt3f